# Plot Top-5 for a Two Column Data Frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the Top 5 in a data frame with two variables by descending order. Both variables are factors. I want to consider the frequency of both variables when plotting, just like a pivot table in excel.

I tried to use tidy to group, count, and sort order of the variables by descending order.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Create a data frame that simulates the data that needs to be modeled

#Create data frame that will hold data for simulation                    

df1 = as.data.frame(replicate(2, sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D",       
  "E","F","G","H","I","J"), 50, rep=TRUE)))

#Replace V2 column with System Nomenclature (Simulated)
df1$V2 <- sample(1:4, replace = TRUE, nrow(df1))

#Make V2 into a Factor
df1$V2 = as.factor(df1$V2)

#Create frequency table
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(V1, V2) %>%
summarise(counts = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
arrange(desc(counts))

#Plot the 2 variable data
ggplot(df2, aes(reorder(x = V1, -counts) , y = counts, fill = V2)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I expect to the graph to plot the data in descending order by the frequency of V1 but with the fill of V2. Just like the pivot table feature in excel. I also want to only display the Top-5 by frequency of V1 and fill with V2.

Comment: Is this any different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393559/arrange-a-two-variable-bar-plot-in-descending-order

Comment: Yes. I want to plot the Top-5 only.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use "scale_x_discrete" to tell ggplot how to order the bars:

```
scale_x <- summarise(group_by(df2, V1), sum_counts = sum(counts)) %>% arrange(desc(sum_counts))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = V1 , y = counts, fill = V2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = scale_x$V1)
```

Comment: Yes. But i then want to plot the Top-5 and preserve the count of the fill = V2.